# Get rid of magic method warning

Tags: phpstorm

Is there any way to get rid of this annoying PhpStorm warning:

```
Member has private access, but class has magic method __get
```

Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately no. See my comment to the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38004272/783119 . The author of that question decided to just hide all warnings altogether... which is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop this inspection: "Member has protected access, but class has magic method \_\_get"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004272/how-to-stop-this-inspection-member-has-protected-access-but-class-has-magic-m)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can turn off warnings for magically accessing properties in the following way:

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections
2. Go to PHP -> Undefined -> Undefined field
3. Uncheck the box for "Notify about access to a field via magic method"

I am not entirely sure if this will also hide the warning in your case, for accessing private members. If not, you could also use the @property PHPDoc tag to describe which fields are accessible through your magic __get method.

Check [this page](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.property.pkg.html) for more information